# Criando um like com node.js e mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Estou criando um like onde a ação pode ser feita uma unica vez por pessoa, realizo a ação com o usuário X na primeira vez e funciona e se ele tentar de novo ele não consegue, mas quando outra pessoa da o like o usuário X consegue mesmo com o nome dela já salvo, estou salvando os nomes das pessoas que dão like em um array dentro do receptor.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Grap = mongoose.model('Usuario');
const Grap2 = mongoose.model('Job');

module.exports = {
async store(req, res){
    const { user } = req.headers;//pega o usuario logado.
    const { devId } = req.params;//pega o usuario selecionado e não logado.

    const UsuarioLogado = await Grap.findById(user);//não preciso mexer em nada aqui.
    const UsuarioReceptor = await Grap2.findById(devId);//Quem recebe o like

    try{
        if(UsuarioLogado.nome == UsuarioReceptor.nome)//para que o criador não possa dar like em si mesmo
            return res.status(400).json({error: 'Você não pode se avaliar'})

        UsuarioReceptor.likes.push(UsuarioLogado.nome);

        await UsuarioReceptor.save();//salva dentro do array.

    }catch{
        return res.status(400).send({error:'fail'});
    }

    return res.json(UsuarioLogado);//retorna para o usuario logado.
  }
};
```

e é aqui onde os likes são salvos

```
const SearchSchema = new Schema({
_id:{
    type: String,
    required: true,
},
nick:{
    type: String,
    required: true,
},
nome:{
    type: String,
    required: true,
},
elo:{
    type: String,
    required: true,
},
num:{
    type: String,
    required: false,
},
wpp:{
    type: String,
    required: true,
},
likes:{
    type: [String], <-- os likes são salvos aqui
    unique:false
},
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro você terá que filtrar os usuários dentro do array

```
const UsuarioReceptor = await Grap2.findById(devId);//não preciso mexer em nada aqui.

    --> const filterRocket = UsuarioReceptor.likes.filter(likes => likes.includes(UsuarioLogado.nome)); <-- adiciona isso

    try{
```

e depois fazer a comparação

```
   if(UsuarioLogado.nome == filterRocket)//para que o usuário não possa dar like duas vezes.
            return res.status(400).json({error: 'Você Já deixou o seu like'})//retorna o aviso.
```